# I'm going to be auto aupdating info from mysql. How do i get the past info to keep displaying along with the new info submitted into the database?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, database, auto-update

I've figured out how to display info submitted into mysql, but I haven't figured out how to keep the past info there. It's going to show the current post on top and keep adding on top everytime new info is submitted but only display like 10 posts at a time. I hope I am explaining this well.

How to go about doing this, I am completely lost. I've connected to the database and everything and now im to:

```
echo $hit, $amount, $category;
```

and stuck. that is displaying the info submitted, but when i submit new info, that info changes and the past info is gone. My question is, how would i get the past info to stay and get the new info to build on top of past info?

Thanks.

Edit: here's more of the code. also, ive been told about mysqli. i just havent changed it yet.

```
if(!$link){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link); 

if(!$db_selected){
    die('can not use' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}
$hit = $_POST['hit'];
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$category = $_POST['category'];



$sql = "INSERT into hit (hit, amount, category) VALUES ('$hit', '$amount', '$category')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

if(!mysql_query($sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_Error());
}
 echo $hit, $amount, $category;

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: The only line of code you posted is the only irrelevant one to this question. All the other ones are needed to properly know your problem.

Answer (score 0):

After the insert sql you need to do a select query to retrieve all the rows from the database as you are only echoing the currently set values.

You need to also be mindful of sql injection as the values you're adding to the database are not sanitised in any way. Use a command such as mysql_real_esape_string or htmlentities for this.

Before the line echoing the results...

```
 echo $hit, $amount, $category;
```

You need to have a select query combined with a while loop and the mysql_fetch_array or mysql_fetch_assoc commands to output the rows from the database. A first check is to see if the records are being added to the table.

Comment: Thanks to the both of you. I would have never known i was suppose to fetch data. i'm obviously still a noob with all of this. so i fetched the data (i think) with this code 'while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
 
 Print "<tr>"; 
 Print "<th>Hit:</th> <td>".$row['hit'] . "</td> "; 
 Print "<th>Amount:</th> <td>".$row['amount'] . " </td></tr>"; 
 Print "<th>Category:</th> <td>".$row['category'] . "</td> ";
 } 
 Print "</table>";' and now all of the data is posting in 3's. more gets posted even when i refresh. i really need to read more on this.

Comment: That's about right, there are plenty of examples and tutorials via google if you search on 'php and mysql crud' (crud is an acronym for create, read, update and delete).

Answer (score 0):

At no point in your code are you fetching data from the database. You're simply submitting the data from the form to mysql, and displaying it at the same time.

You can fetch data from mysql by doing something like this:

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT hit, amount, category FROM hit");
// Adding MYSQL_ASSOC as a second argument tells mysql_fetch_array that
// we want an associative array (we can refer to fields by their name, not just by number)
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<p>'
    .'Hit: ' . $row['hit']
    .', Amount: ' . $row['amount']
    .', Category: ' . $row['category']
    .'</p>';
}
```

Keep in mind this is all a simplified version of things, and it needs more work, especially on security. I should probably be using `htmlentities()` here, depending on the data. And you should definitely be protecting against SQL injection if that data is coming directly from a user.

Comment: hmmm... @user466764 answered while I was writing this, and probably took the better approach in not giving an actual block of code. I'd say it's best to use his answer and refer to the php manual to learn about the functions he's mentioned. Especially (once you get the basic queries working) `mysql_real_escape_string`, as the code at the moment is very insecure. 
I can't seem to comment on other people's answers right now, I guess because of low rep

Comment: Ciaran thanks for still responding. Like i just said, i would have never known i wasnt fetching data if it wasnt for you two. and ive never even heard of htmlentities().. so i'm looking this stuff up now. thanks again.

Comment: No problem! :D
In phpmyadmin there should be a window or textbox for running SQL queries directly. I'd say practice running your SQL queries there until you get the hang of the basic operations and keywords, and can easily select, update and delete data with various conditions.

Then you can come back to the PHP side of things when you've got your head around that and it'll be much easier as you'll already understand how to interact with a database. At the moment you're trying to get the hang of PHP and SQL at exactly the same time, and it's just going to lead to confusion.